# How to show page loading percentage using jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, page-load-time

I want to show page loading like 1%, 2%, 3% .... 100% using jquery. but it is showing only 100%;

```
 var count = 0;

    while(count<100){
        $("#load-perc").text(count+1+"%").delay(200).fadeIn("slow");
        count++;
    }
```

i tried animation also but nothing worked.

```
$("#load-perc").html(count+1+"%").animate({'opacity': 1}, 400);
```

Can you please help me to show loading like 1%, 2%, 3% .... 100%

Comment: you're not waiting in the loop for the previous value to be shown before commencing to set the next value

Comment: I tried .show() and dealy() also but these are also not showing value one by one.

Answer (score 0):

In vanilla JS: Make an interval and you can control the speed by changing the time.
More the time, slower the speed.

In jQuery:
Use the animate function to make the counter.

```js
// Vanilla JS
let time = 20
let start = 0
let end = 100
let counter = setInterval(() => {
  if (start != end) {
    document.getElementById('loader').innerHTML = start + '%'
    start += 1
  } else {
    clearInterval(counter)
    document.getElementById('loader').innerHTML='100%'
  }
}, time)

// Pure jQuery
$('#jqueryLoader').prop('Counter', 0).animate({
  Counter: 100
}, {
  duration: 2000,
  easing: 'swing',
  step: function(now) {
    $(this).text(Math.ceil(now)+'%');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='loader'></div>
<div id='jqueryLoader'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

here's a solution that doesn't depend on timeout's

It uses the `complete` callback of `fadeIn` to resolve a promise that is chained

created `fn` to make things easier

```js
var count = 0;
var p = Promise.resolve();
var fn = (perc) => {
  p = p.then(() => new Promise(resolve => $("#load-perc").text(perc + "%").delay(200).fadeIn("slow", resolve)));
};
while (count < 100) {
  fn(count + 1);
  count++;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="load-perc"></div>
```

With a `for` loop it's much neater though

```js
var p = Promise.resolve();
for (let count = 1; count <= 100; count ++) {
  p = p.then(() => new Promise(resolve => $("#load-perc").text(count + "%").delay(200).fadeIn("slow", resolve)));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="load-perc"></div>
```